# Unable to install (Nokia PC Suite) Nokuntu on 13.10 & 14.04

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, nokia

Trying to install `Nokuntu` on Ubuntu 13.10

But showing the below error.

[image]

Installed `gambas3` but not solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing anything you have to run a package install command to install a lot of packages which are available in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install comerr-dev krb5-multidev libaudio-dev libcups2-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libgssrpc4 libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev libkadm5clnt-mit8 libkadm5srv-mit8 libkdb5-6 libkrb5-dev liblcms1-dev libmng-dev libp11-kit-dev libtasn1-3-dev libxcursor-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev bwidget gsm-utils libbfb0 libgsmme1c2a libmulticobex1 libobexftp0 obexfs obexftp obextool openobex-apps syncevolution tcllib tklib
```

Then install these packages:

```
fuse-utils_2.8.6-2ubuntu2_all.deb
gambas2-gb-form_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb
gambas2-gb-gtk_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
gambas2-gb-gui_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
gambas2-gb-pcre_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
gambas2-gb-qt_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
gambas2-gb-settings_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb
gambas2-gb-xml_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
gambas2-runtime_2.23.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
libqt3-headers_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
libqt3-mt-dev_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

(and probably other packages) all available in http://packages.ubuntu.com/ (select precise 12.04 packages always).

Then you may be able to install

```
nokuntusp_0.5.9-1_all.deb
```

or

```
nokuntusp_0.6-1_all.deb
```

Then in terminal run this command:

```
sudo nokuntusp.gambas
```

To get a window like this:
[image]

With most functionalities disabled at least in initial encounters, and with nokia x3 mobile hard-set connected with usb. Not so interesting and useful it seemed to me.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libkadm5clnt-mit8
E: Unable to locate package libkdb5-6

Comment: probably you have upgraded to 14.04 or a normal source is missing. btw, I recommend to forget this so badly developed software. However it may be because the deveoper has chosen gambas,

Comment: Is there any other software like this?

Comment: @FaisalHaqSalafi: Wammu partially works for Nokia Phone. However it seems there's not a complete alternative.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/), the development of Nokuntu has stopped, so it was newer updated to use the Gambas 3 runtime.

As the deprecated Gambas 2 runtime is not included anymore in Ubuntu 13.04 and above, the best option is to just install the package from 12.10. You can download the right package for your architecture [from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/gambas2-runtime) and install it on your system.